# Using connect vhost to serve multiple express.js apps

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vhosts, node.js-connect

I want to use connect's vhost functionality to deploy  several express.js apps to my dev vps. Here is my server.js file that is supposed to send requests to the appropriate place:

```
var express = require('express')
var quotes = require('quote-of-the-day/lib/app.js');    
var server = express();  
server.use(express.vhost('inspiringquoteoftheday.com',quotes));    
server.listen(80);
```

Running node server.js throws this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'quote-of-the-day/lib/app.js'
```

Even though I can cd into app.js straight from the directory where server.js is located.

Here is the lib/app.js file in which I export my express app (I think)

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.3.3
(function() {
  var app, express, pub;

  express = require('express');

  module.exports = app = express();

  pub = __dirname + '/public';

  app.use(express["static"](pub));

  app.use(express.errorHandler());

  app.use(app.router);

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

  app.set('view engine', 'jade');

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return res.render('home');
  });

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a directory structure that looks something like this:

```
|-. quote-of-the-day
  |-- server.js <-- the file you list in your question
  |-. lib
    |-- app.js
```

Then you should require your `app.js` with

```
require('./lib/app');
```

Comment: My directory structure was a bit different... but I forgot that nice little ./ due to not being on ubuntu for a bit. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful to use the __dirname global variable here. 
it provides 'the name of the directory that the currently executing script resides in.'
thus you could do:

`var otherApp = require(__dirname + 'quote-of-the-day/lib/app.js')`

http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html